# Fit text in span box CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have class that should handle warning messages in my system. This works fin for majority of the messages. Recently I had to output longer message and that cause span warning box to break. Instead of breaking the box in separate line I would like the box to expand the height and text break in separate line. I'm not sure if I can achieve that with CSS. Here is my working example:

```
span.info, .success, .warning, .error {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

span.warning {
    color: #9F6000;
    background-color: #FEEFB3;
    background-image: url('../Images/warning.png');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/jhhabr1u/

If anyone knows how this can be fixed please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Provide code. SO doesn't allow jsfiddle links without supplemental code so you obviously saw that message already because you tried to "trick" SO by putting your URL as "code"

Comment: `span` is an inline element. set it to `display:block`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just need to make the span display block

```
span{
  display: block;
}
```

```css
span.info, .success, .warning, .error {
 border: 1px solid;
 margin: 5px;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 40px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 10px center;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
span{
  display: block;
}

span.warning {
 color: #9F6000;
 background-color: #FEEFB3;
 background-image: url('../Images/warning.png');
}
```

```html
<span class="warning">This user already exist in the system. Check the name and DOB and if the information is correct please contact your administrator.</span>
```

Comment: And if you're doing that, consider using divs.

Comment: @isherwood Do you mean to put the span inside of the div element?

Comment: No. Spans are intended to be inline elements. If you're forcing block display, why not just use appropriate block-level elements?

Comment: @isherwood Do you suggest using table elements or?

Comment: That depends on your content. Tables should only be use for tabular data. Please post a new question if you have one.